# How can I resume an upload to ftp from php

Tags: php, ftp

I have a php-script that uploads files to an ftp server from a location with a very low bandwith, low reliability connection. I am currently using the [ftp functions of php](http://php.net/ftp).

Sometimes the connection drops in the middle of a transfer. Is there a way to later resume the upload? How can this be done?

**Edit:**
People misunderstood that this is happening from a browser. However, this is not the case. It is a php cli script. So it is about a local file being uploaded to ftp, no user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the remote file's size and then issuing the APPE ftp command with the difference. This will append to the file. See http://webmasterworld.com/forum88/4703.htm for an example. If you want real control over this, I recommend using PHP's cURL functions.

Comment: Your link is broken, but the idea is indeed what I need. If you repair your link I will happily upvote...

Answer (score 2):

I think all the previous answers are wrong. The PHP manage the resume, for that FTP_AUTODESK must be activated, and you have to activate the FTP_AUTORESUME during upload. The code should be something like this :

```
$ftp_connect = ftp_connect($host, $port);
ftp_set_option ($ftp_connect, FTP_AUTOSEEK, TRUE);
$stream = fopen($local_file, 'r');
$upload = ftp_fput($ftp_connect, $file_on_ftp, $stream, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: Sorry for the 5-year bump, but are you sure the FTP_AUTORESUME parameter goes at the end of the ftp_put() argument list?  This argument position is supposed to be for seek position (an integer).  Looking at the docs (which actually say very little), I would think the correct usage would be to issue an `ftp_set_option($ftp_connect,FTP_AUTORESUME,true)` before calling ftp_fput()...?

Comment: @Doin `FTP_AUTORESUME` is a Constant and it is equal to `-1`

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_(f)put` has a $startpos parameter. You should be able to do what you need using this parameter. (starts the transfer from the file size on your server).
However I never used it, so I don't know about the reliability. You should try.

Comment: Where is this $startpos parameter documented? Is it really starting from that byte at both the client and the remote file?

Comment: If this answer would be expanded, I could change my accepted answer to it and upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
[Another Example](https://gist.github.com/cballou/3781156): by cballou

[Look here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php#refsect1-function.ftp-nb-put-examples). A very simple and good example.

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
     $host = 'your.host.name';
     $user = 'user';
     $passwd = 'yourpasswd';


     $ftp_stream = ftp_connect($host);
     //EDIT
     ftp_set_option($ftp_stream, FTP_AUTOSEEK, 1);
     if ( ftp_login($ftp_stream,$user,$passwd) ){
        //activate passive mode
        //ftp_pasv($ftp_stream, TRUE);

        $ret = ftp_nb_put($ftp_stream, $remotefile, $localfile, FTP_BINARY,FTP_AUTORESUME);
        while ( FTP_MOREDATA == $ret ) {
            // continue transfer
            $ret = ftp_nb_continue($ftp_stream);
        }

        if (FTP_FINISHED !== $ret){
           echo 'Failure occured on transfer ...';
        } 
     }
     else {
         print "FAILURE while login ...";

     }

     //free
     ftp_close($ftp_stream);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the FTP_AUTORESUME parameter goes at the end of the ftp_nb_put() argument list?  This argument position is supposed to be for seek position (an integer).  Looking at the docs (which actually say very little), I would think the correct usage would be to issue an `ftp_set_option($ftp_connect,FTP_AUTORESUME,true)` before calling ftp_nb_put()...?

Comment: I refer here only to the documentation of PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php#example-4831 and http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.constants.php#constant.ftp-autoresume. Yes you are right in this spot I forgot the `ftp_set_option ($ftp_stream, FTP_AUTOSEEK, true);`

Comment: `FTP_AUTORESUME (integer)
Automatically determine resume position and start position for GET and PUT requests (only works if FTP_AUTOSEEK is enabled)`

Answer (score -1):

are you meaning you are going to allow user resume upload from you web interface ?
is this suit you ?
http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3931706.htm

Comment: please text proper next time but don't waste time and credit of other folk !!
sorry for any text that make you feel uncomfortable...

Comment: Wasting time of other folk? In my original question I was already clearly talking about uploading from php with the ftp functions. I don't know where you got the idea that it had anything to do with the web interface. That you wasted your time is not my fault.

Answer (score -2):

just use the filezilla can done everything for you ...i mean the uploading process...
it will keep the data and reopen after close you will be able to continue process q...

for automate and tracking , simply use our way...which is git and capistrano
there is an option for php
try google it...

Comment: You haven't read the question. He needs to do this programatically.